# Rails model validation which check if already exists object with some property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have following model:

```
class TestModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum some_column: [:prop1, :prop2, :prop3]
end
```

I want to ensure i will always have maximum one object with prop1 column value in database, while i can have multiple numbers of object with prop2 or prop3 objects or none of them. It would be great if it could be a model validation. I tried this way but not sure if this is good practice for a rails app:

```
      if ((id.nil? and TestModel.where(some_column: 'prop1')) or (TestModel.where(some_column: 'prop1').where.not(id: id)))
```

I tried with left side to cover create action, with right side to cover update. Is there any rails way to do this?

Thanks

**UPDATED**

This is solution for my problem

```
def only_one_prop1_record
  if(some_column == 'prop1')
    if new_record? #if create action
      if TestModel.where(some_column: 'prop1').any?
        errors.add(:base, 'You can only have one prop1 record')
      end
    elsif persisted? #if update action
      if TestModel.where(some_column: 'prop1').where.not(id: id).any?
        errors.add(:base, 'You can only have one prop1 record')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And call validation like this: `validate :only_one_prop1_record`

Comment: I believe there's no rails out of the box way to do that. You need to create a custom validation.

Comment: you should not put your answer in your own question - you should put it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you:

```
class TestModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum some_column: [:prop1, :prop2, :prop3]

  validate :only_one_prop1_record, on: :create

  def only_one_prop1_record
    if TestModel.exists?(some_column: prop1)
      errors.add(:base, 'You can only have one prop1 record')
    end
  end
end
```

Or may be to run the validation on `update` and `create` both you can try this:

```
def only_one_prop1_record
  existing_record = TestModel.where(some_column: prop1).first
  if (new_record? && existing_record.present?) || (persisted? && existing_record != self)
    errors.add(:base, 'You can only have one prop1 record')
  end
end
```

And remove the `on: :create` from above.

Comment: Validation fails when i try to update object with prop1 attribute.

Comment: I needed to add some_column == 'prop1' at start of if statement,  i could not create new records ,  because validation doesn't allow it if i have prop1 object. Thanks, i made it